# Converting from mysql to SQL SERVER

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I am working on a project where I am migrating from mysql to SQL server. I have actually looked for equivalent functions, but haven't found it. I have came this far and have been able to connect to my DB, the next was to select all from pools and show it in the HTML select (dropdown) options. I am unsure if it's just to convert the mysqli_query to sqlsrv_query e.g ?

Hope someone could be able to show me the correct path for solving my issue.

```
<?php
$conn_array = array (
"UID" => "sa",
"PWD" => "root",
"Database" => "nih_bw",
) ;

$conn = sqlsrv_connect('TEST' , $conn_array);

if ($conn)
{

$result = mysqli_query($con,"Select name from pools");

    echo "<select name='mypool' class='form-control'>";

    $default_name = "foo_bar"; 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
      $opt_name = $row['name'];
      $str_selected = "";
      if($opt_name == $default_name){
          $str_selected = "selected";
    }
      echo "<option value='".$opt_name."' ".$str_selected." >" . $opt_name. "</option>";
    }

    echo "</select>";

}
else
{
die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

sqlsrv_close( $conn );

?>
```

Comment: Start here http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php Or here http://webcheatsheet.com/php/connect_mssql_database.php

Comment: I am very unsure how that would be implemented in my case.

Comment: OR maybe you want other people to do the work for you.

Comment: No, absolutely not! I want to learn by my self, thats the point of life.

Comment: Switch to PDO. The `mssql_*` functions are just as bad as `mysql_*`, and had you been using it in the first place the only difference in your code would likely be the connection string.

Comment: What about the sqlsrv functions ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$conn = mssql_connect('Host', 'User', 'Password');

if (!$conn || !mssql_select_db('database', $conn)) {
    die('Unable to connect or select database! <br> ' . sqlsrv_errors());
} else {
    $result = mssql_query($con, "Select name from pools");

    echo "<select name='mypool' class='form-control'>";

    $default_name = "foo_bar";
    while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $opt_name = $row['name'];
        $str_selected = "";
        if ($opt_name == $default_name) {
            $str_selected = "selected";
        }
        echo "<option value='" . $opt_name . "' " . $str_selected . " >" . $opt_name . "</option>";
    }

    echo "</select>";
}

mssql_free_result($result);
mssql_close($conn);
?>
```

Hope it works for you! Check php manual for MS SQL connectivity at http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php

Editing after comments! mssql failed to run?

MS SQL Client Tools to be installed on the system where PHP is installed to work it properly. copy ntwdblib.dll from \winnt\system32 on the server to \winnt\system32 on the PHP box. Copying ntwdblib.dll will only provide access through named pipes. Configuration of the client will require installation of all the tools. This extension is not available anymore on Windows with PHP 5.3 or later. Install appropriate extensions or use sqlsrv which also requires some installation!

**sqlsrv_connect**, 
**sqlsrv_query**, 
**sqlsrv_fetch_array**, 
**sqlsrv_errors** and 
**sqlsrv_close** functions are available to work with. More functions are available at PHP sqlsrv manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.sqlsrv.php

Comment: Hmm! Get this error:  Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect()

Comment: MS SQL Client Tools to be installed on the system where PHP is installed. ntwdblib.dll from \winnt\system32 on the server to \winnt\system32 on the PHP box. Copying ntwdblib.dll will only provide access through named pipes. Configuration of the client will require installation of all the tools.

This extension is not available anymore on Windows with PHP 5.3 or later.